# How to redirect pages with a parametre?

Tags: .htaccess, parameters

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/abcd.html&p=1
http://stackoverflow.com/answers/wxyz.html&p=5
http://stackoverflow.com/database/mnop.html&p=167

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/abcd.html?p=1
http://stackoverflow.com/answers/wxyz.html?p=5
http://stackoverflow.com/database/mnop.html?p=167
http://stackoverflow.com/order/anything.html?mode=new
http://stackoverflow.com/checkout/something.html?mode=old
```

I want to redirect all urls like these to:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/abcd.html
http://stackoverflow.com/answers/wxyz.html
http://stackoverflow.com/database/mnop.html
http://stackoverflow.com/order/anything.html
http://stackoverflow.com/checkout/something.html
```

Please suugest me.

Comment: What's doing the redirecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to remove all URL parameters then?  Given that this question is tagged to .htaccess, I assume that's what you want to use to do your redirect.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?.*$  $1  [L,R=301]
```

This rule basically says, given me everything that is in the format `*?*`, and then just ignore all the content that occurs after the question mark.

Comment: Thanks, but, what is the code for first situation? That's what confusing me, without query just ampersand and parameter.

Comment: That's not technically a valid URL, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about a web server, and that server is apache, take a look at mod_rewrite.

http://www.elated.com/articles/mod-rewrite-tutorial-for-absolute-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code
But the best way doing this in frontend webserver (nginx e.t.c)

```
if (preg_match('@^(.+)\?.+@Uis', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches)) {
  header('Location: ' . $matches[1]);
  exit;
}
```